# SSL/TLS certificate management (key, crt, and pem)

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2, netcat, socat

I have a question about TLS/SSL (self-signed certificates)

I am trying to open a connection using several tools (ncat, socat) by using TLS/SSL.
Of course first i need to generate certificate. (Key is a KEY, and Cert is a CERT, PEM is an encoded format). I have found 2 different ways.

```
1) openssl req -new -x509 -keyout test-key.pem -out test-cert.pem.

2) openssl req -newkey rsa:2848 -nodes -keyout test.key -x589 -out test-cert.crt
   cat test-key.key test-cert.crt > test-pem.pem
```

My questions:

1. Why at the end of the day we combine CERT with KEY? Should not CERT already have KEY inside?
2. Why on most tutorials, we send(by listener on socat/ncat) key with cert, if cert already have a key?

(Assume we do not verify cert)

Thanks for support.

SOLVED.

Comment: From what i have understood, test-crt.crt file does not include key itself. So that was a misunderstanding. Sorry for misleading, it was due to bad tutorial.

Comment: A comment is not the place to answer a question - even it is your own. If you feel that the question is worthless and there is no need to answer it ever properly then just delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should not CERT already have KEY inside?

The certificate has the **public** key inside. The key file is the **private** key. The public key can be visible to others (as does the rest of the certificate), the private key should be kept secret.

Comment: cat test-key.key test-cert.crt > test-pem.pem ---- Then what is the purpose of this command? Why we connect private key with cert? Would not be it logical to provide them separately to socat-ncat after we have generated them?

Comment: @LORDNIGHTSHIELD: it is actually usually given as separate arguments. For example `socat` has a `key` and `cert` argument for this. Only if no explicit `key` is given it will look into the file given by `cert` not only for the certificate but also for the key.